# Generating nunit test result when a test fails

Tags: nunit-console

I am currently working with the nunit-console. I have a dll which have 8 tests. To run the test a bat file has been created with following command:

nunit-console.exe Sample.dll Result.xml

This runs all the tests & generates the result after completion of entire tests. What I need is to get the result when a single test fails & stop further testing so that i dont have to wait for the entire test to complete.

Is there any thing I can do with the bat file and without touching the source code of Sample.dll.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The flag you're looking for on the command line is /stoponerror

From the documentation:

> The /stoponerror option causes execution of the test run to terminate immediately on the first test failure or error.

The documentation page is here: http://nunit.com/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6

Comment: I found this does not work. Tests still keep running